# What will happen when a class inherits a public method with reference to private properties?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I defined private properties `hp` and `atk` for `warrior` class and supposed that they won't
be inherited by derived classes.

In the following code, however, The derived class `knight` inherits a public method `attack` which
calls the private property `atk`. In this case, knight.attack() still functions properly and seems to have access to the private property `atk` though it wasn't supposed to be inherited by a derived class.

I am confused about this. Could you please help me to explain the mechanism behind the scene?
**When I create an instance of `knight` class, does it have the `atk` property?**

```
#include <cstdio>
class warrior{
    private:
        int hp,atk;
    public:
        void attack(int &enemyHP) {
            enemyHP -= this->atk;
            printf("Deal %d damage to the enemy.\n", this->atk);
            this->atk += 10;
        }
        warrior(int hp=100, int atk=20) {
            this->hp = hp; this->atk = atk;
        }
};
class knight:public warrior{
    public:
        knight(int hp=200, int atk=50) {}
};
int main()
{
    int enemyHP=100;
    knight Tom = knight();
    Tom.attack(enemyHP); // Deal 20 damage to the enemy.
    Tom.attack(enemyHP); // Deal 30 damage to the enemy.
}
```

Comment: Private properties **are** inherited, they are just not _accessible_ to the derived class. A `knight` _is a_ `warrior` that also has a separate constructor. By the way, the default values you've defined in the `knight` constructor will not be applied because they are not passed into the `warrior` constructor.

Comment: Members of a class are determined by the definition oft the class. Deriving from a base class doesn’t change the base class.

Comment: *"though it wasn't supposed to be inherited by a derived class."* - you're confusing inheritance with *accessibility*. You can have the former without the latter.

Answer (score 1):

> When I create an instance of knight class, does it have the atk property?

Yes, it does. But only methods inherited from `warrior` can access it. The goal of `private` is to limit *visibility* to the class that defines it, but it still *exists* in the child classes as well, they just can't access it (not without resorting to undefined behavior nonsense like accessing the raw bytes of the instance anyway). But since a `knight` is a `warrior`, when it uses `warrior` behaviors (methods defined on `warrior` itself), they can see `atk` just fine.

This is fine; `atk` isn't part of `knight`'s public interface, but `attack` is, and for `attack` to work, it needs to see `warrior`'s `atk`. By hiding `warrior`'s `atk` from *direct* access, you've done enough to ensure `knight` *could* declare it's own `atk` member (which would be 100% independent of `warrior`'s `atk`, and if also declared `private` would only be accessible from methods defined on `knight`). Regardless, it does what it should do:

1. Public methods continue to work when inherited, even if they operate on private members
2. Private attributes can't be accessed by anything not defined as part of their own class (unless made accessible via `friend`)